# Software Center doesn't prompt for password

Tags: 10.10, software-center, password, policykit

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.
The software center was asking me for password when I wanted to install/remove any application. Since last week, it doesn't prompt for password. Also, I have the same problem with `update-manager`. However, Synaptic and `sudo apt-get` ask for password. 
How to fix this?

this is link to the files that you guys need to know

[sudoers file](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1qnIRRCcbK5OKqOdA_OLCsMJQBzPZ4P9FcLe8Vrw8mDg)

[/etc/polkit-1](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1lPM2jF9s-bS2nxSqkU4Fs819dUW8TXl4KGomE6_kKlU)

[/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.debian.apt.policy](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1Mr9ByQ0LCXRjbR0hC7QJjkJuhmwiMrb6fj_Q8m2fbeQ)

[sudo grep -IR '^[^#]' /var/lib/polkit-1](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19wsi2kU0p9ZLyziNajevfqOAMc8pYtxB7xYt62HAI9k)

[grep '^[^#]' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20dbus /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.debian.apt.conf /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.debian.apt.service](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1ApJaDOPTYzYAq3Mj5yMAGyCK5CcRHkziM1321rHfXl0)

Comment: What is the output of your /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: That's unreadable without the newlines, and it seem to be missing the last part. Could you put that in your question instead? Also, keep in mind that once you type in the password once, it'll "remember" it for about 15 minutes.

Comment: The difference between update-manager/software center and synaptic/apt-get is the policykit integration in the former pair -- the issue may lie there

Comment: @geirha I know it will remember the password for 15 minutes but the last time i put the password was last week!

Comment: @jasonbrooks how I can check it if the issues there or not? what I have to do?

Comment: Unless there's a serious bug in sudo, the problem is not with that sudoers file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already said, the problem may be your *PolicyKit* configuration. I would be interested in the contents of the files in `/etc/polkit-1` directory and the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.debian.apt.policy`. The output can be lengthy, so you may want to compress it and upload it somewhere rather than copy it here...

> grep -IR '^[^#]' /etc/polkit-1
>
> cat /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.debian.apt.policy

EDIT: After you've uploaded the files I can see that the problem is in your `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/20-xbmclive.pkla` file which seems to have been installed by XBMC and effectively turns off all authentication via polkit (why it has done so and if it is really needed I don't know, I don't use this software).

```
[XBMC-Live user permissions]
Identity=unix-user:azizjoh
Action=*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: I upload it as a GoogleDoc see the link Up at the end of the question

thanks

Comment: I don't see in the output any reason why it should not work... Could you also post `sudo grep -IR '^[^#]' /var/lib/polkit-1` and `grep '^[^#]' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20dbus /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.debian.apt.conf /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.debian.apt.service`?

Comment: I add it to the question

Comment: see my edit in the original answer

Comment: I comment all the lines in the file that you said to me. XBMC still work and the software center prompting for password `thanks`