# Can't install applications on software center

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software Center doesn't prompt for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22649/software-center-doesnt-prompt-for-password)

I try to install apps on software center and nothing happens it does'nt ask me to enter my password or anything when i click install it so annoying... It's for all apps.....

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I cannot answer your question, it's very likely that you are still able to install apps via the terminal.

I would recommend trying Synaptic Package Manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic-pkexec
```

Good luck with the bug! Synaptic Package Manager isn't as pretty, but it's just as good

Comment: OK thanks but if i wanted an app from the web would i have to search it in Synaptic Package Manager?